# Why z-index is not working with opacity and transform

Tags: html, css

Hey guys I faced the confusion with stacking context in CSS, that is, as you can see in the code below I used opacity: .99; to create stacking context for both boxes and decided to use z-index for orange box but the orange box is not placed above green one. Why? I thought it is possible to use z-index with elements having transform and opacity attributes. My second question is that since I am beginner I just wanted to ask why when I create stacking context using opacity or transform for a certain element (say div) that div element  is placed above other static elements. Is z-index added to the element behind the scenes or something like that.

```css
.green {
  background: green;
  height: 250px;
  width: 1090px;
  margin-top: -70px;
  opacity: .99;
}

.orange {
  background: orange;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  opacity: .99;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="orange">Orange</div>
<div class="green">Green</div>
```

Comment: to trigger z-index you need to reset position to relative(or absolute/fixed) or use transform, else , z-index has no effects.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: for your second question it's about painting order (Am adding another duplicate)

Answer (score 1):

`z-index` only applies to *positioned elements*, which are elements where the `position` property has a value other than `static` (which is the default).

Set `position: relative`.

Comment: No. I don't have twenty minutes to spend.